# Treating 1D array (pointer) as 3D matrix at run time in C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I receive some image data as `unsigned char *image = load_image(…);`

This data is a 3D matrix: `x` (char),`y` (char) and `channel (RGB)` (char).

How can I access each element as `image[x][y][channel]`?

> e.g. row 999, column 10000, green channel: `image[999][10000][1]`

Clarifications:

1. I'd like to use C multi-dimensional array syntax:

   > `array[x][y][z]`, not `array[x * height * channels + y * channels + z]`
2. I can access a 1D array as a 2D array:

   > `unsigned char (*imageMatrix)[height] = (unsigned char (*)[height])image`
   >   `imageMatrix[x][y] = 100`

Comment: what are the `types` of `x`, `y` and `channel`?

Comment: `image[row * width * 3 + column * 3 + channel]` assuming all color values are packed tight with no padding anywhere.

Comment: I updated the question to clarify I'd like array syntax, thanks

Comment: And I'd like a pony. I'm afraid we both will have to manage without. You could write a helper function or class that takes the three coordinates and returns the corresponding element.

Comment: I can access a 1D array as a 2D array: `unsigned char (*imageMatrix)[height] = (unsigned char (*)[height]) image;`. I guess it's possible to access it as 3D as well, I just can't see how

Comment: Here, either `height` is a compile-time constant, or you are using variable-length arrays, which are not valid in C++ but accepted by some compilers as an extension. If that's OK with you (that is, that the image dimensions must be hard-coded at compile time or that your code is non-portable), then just cast to `unsigned char (*)[height][channels]` the same way.

Comment: It can be done (correctly) in both C and C++, but not with the same tools. In C (post C99) you can use pointers to Variable Length Arrays, while in C++ you would overload the operator []. Please choose one language (and optionaly ask another question for the alternate one, refering to the original one).

Comment: Any particular reason you want do access it in this specific way? if it's just for convenience, you could use a macro to define something like `ARRAY3D(x, y, z)  x * height * channels + y * channels + z`, and then access it as  `image[ARRAY3D(999, 10000, 1)]`, or you can overload the `[]`  operator to do the same.

Comment: for convenience but also to learn the language

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I can get you that pony.

Comment: @ijverig: **Which** language? C and C++ are different languages and this is one case where different concepts should be used...

Comment: @SergeBallesta I restricted this question to C only, thanks

Comment: @IgorTandetnik It's not for the pony :-) I just learned a bunch of type casting, VLA and memory with this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use this: `unsigned char (*imageMatrix)[height] = (unsigned char (*)[height])image,`, then your compiler supports Variable Length Arrays. VLA were introduced in C99 but were made back optional in C11.

But when VLA are supported, you can alias a 1D array to a 3D array exactly the same you alias it to a 2D array:

```
unsigned char (*imageMatrix)[width][channel] = (unsigned char (*)[width][channel])image;
imageMatrix[x][y][channel] = 100;
```

Comment: Ok, thanks! Just one correction: the way you aliased (the order of the VLA) results in accessing the array like `imageMatrix[channel][x][y] = 100`, right?

Comment: @ijverig: Oups, it looks like I got it out of order... Fixed.